# AAD v2 applications manifest

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I'm looking for a documentation/article, similar to that one https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-application-manifest) for v2 applications.

Any tips ?

Regards, Thibaud

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Is there a specific field that's confusing or you want more info about that I can help with right now?

Comment: Hi Daniel, this request is from one of my customer. They use Azure AD without O365, only to integrate SaaS application with AAD. They have pretty deep knowledge on the topic already but due to lack of documentation around v2 attributes, they don’t know how to leverage all of them and what they are used for. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the explanation & clarification.  You can expect to see more docs coming in for v2 pretty soon.  I'd be very interested to hear if there's other specific aspects that are unclear to help guide our efforts.   If you do run into things that need clarification, feel free to reach out directly (email is on my StackOverflow profile).